# Pandas compare strings in cells in two DataFrames with rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and need to replace the values/strings only if it is a certain value/string.

df1

```
- L 1 P
1 1 2 *
1 M 8 1
```

df2

```
3 4 5 6
2 4 5 6
9 8 7 6
```

rule: replace cells in df1 with df2 only if df1 = 1

```
- L 5 P
2 4 2 *
9 M 8 6
```

What would be the python code for that operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert everything to string in `df1` using `df.astype` then use `df.mask` here.

```
df1 = df1.astype(str)
df1.mask(df1.eq('1'), df2)

   0  1  2  3
0  -  L  5  P
1  2  4  2  *
2  9  M  8  6
```